# Not able to understand the Proxy cons

Tags: java, proxy

I was reading about proxy pattern in [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-proxy) and understood the example, but [this comment](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-proxy#comment-103231)confused me. The comment states:

> There are 2 big problems with proxies, especially in enterprise environments.
>
> 1) **You can't do self calls**. A good example is a proxy that does transaction management or security. So you need to make sure that instead of doing a self call, you forward the call to the proxy. This makes simple classes complex.
>
> 2) There are issues with identity; a good examlpe is a hibernate proxy which makes it impossible to do a **reference comparison**, even though you get the guarantee that there are not multiple object instances of the same entity in a session.

My questions:

1. What is the meaning of self call?
2. Why we can not do a reference comparison when both refers to proxy object?

Comment: Who's Peter and where's the *link below*?

Comment: I think Peter left with the link ;-)

Comment: I am very sorry guys, just missed. but now added

Comment: wow Luiggi.. thanks for the edit

Comment: @ How can I know who has downvoted the question, as I want to follow up with those guys and want to understand the reason

Answer (score 4):

1. "Self call" refers to calling a method on the same object, using `otherMethod()` instead of `var.otherMethod()`. Since the call on the same object goes straight through `this` and not the proxy, any special treatment that the proxy would apply doesn't happen.
2. The runtime environment may fiddle around with the proxy object, and you always run the risk of accidentally trying to compare the proxy itself with the business object hiding behind it, as in the case where the object passes a `this` reference out somewhere and somebody trying to compare it looks it back up from the runtime (and gets the proxy).

Comment: Would you please elaborate the second point with an example? Suppose I have abc as a proxy object that is refering to xyz which is actual object. Now could you please explain your second point by this example.