# Query Regarding Proxy Equality

Tags: java, design-patterns, proxy

I was going through the answers of following question:

[Proxy Pattern Cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266390/not-able-to-understand-the-proxy-cons)

One of the answers was:

> The runtime environment may fiddle around with the proxy object, and
>   you always run the risk of accidentally trying to compare the proxy
>   itself with the business object hiding behind it, as in the case where
>   the object passes a this reference out somewhere and somebody trying
>   to compare it looks it back up from the runtime (and gets the proxy).

**Can anyone please elaborate this?** (I have read this line 1000 times but not able to understand this).

Comment: @chrylis Would you please comment on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a service interface:

```
public interface Phone {
    void call(String number, PhoneListener listener);
}
```

And a concrete implementation:

```
public class PhoneImpl implements Phone 

    @Override
    public void call(String number, PhoneListener listener) {
        // perform the phone call
        // chat
        // tell the listener that the call is complete
        listener.callEnded(this);
    }
}
```

Now suppose a class gets two instances from some factory, and this factory actually returns a proxy, because every phone call should be logged by this proxy:

```
public class PhoneHouse {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Phone phone1 = PhoneFactory.getPhone("phone1");
         Phone phone2 = PhoneFactory.getPhone("phone2");
         PhoneListener listener = new PhoneListener() {
             @Override
             public void callEnded(Phone phone) {
                 if (phone.equals(phone1)) {
                     System.out.println("A call ended with phone 1");
                 }
                 else if (phone.equals(phone2)) {
                     System.out.println("A call ended with phone 2");
                 }
             }
         };
         phone1.call("012345678", listener);
         phone2.call("098765432", listener);
     }
}
```

Now what will be displayed on the screen?

The answer is nothing, because the phone passed to the listener's `callEnded()` method is an instance `PhoneImpl`, but `phone1` and `phone2` are proxies wrapping an instance of `PhoneImpl`.

Comment: Did you mean a method named phone instead of call?

Comment: Yes, `call()` would be a better name indeed. And I see that I used phone at the beginning of the post and call at the end. Fixed now.

Comment: Just wanted your input on this..Is this a drawback of Proxy OR its a developer's negligence ?

Comment: It's a little bit of both. If the developer isn't fully aware of the fact that proxies are used, such problems can happen. The code above would work fine if no proxy was used. If proxies are introduced in the factory after this code has been written, it becomes non-functional. So the proxy pattern has an impact. The bug I've seen the most is a Spring or EJB service method calling another method of the same service class annotated with @TRansactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW). Instead of starting a new transaction, it doesn't because the call doesn't go through the proxy wrapping the service.

Comment: Got your point, you mean the call is made on the actual object (this reference), so proxy does not come into picture.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If Possible, Would you please comment on the 4th and 5th point of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259245/downsides-of-proxy-design-pattern

Comment: The question has been closed because it contains 5 different questions. Ask each of them in a separate question if you want. I'll be happy to answer on the last one. I don't really understand what the OP meant with the 4th one.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302183/proxy-design-pattern-disadvantages